# adjacent_difference work with pre and next

Tags: c++

I was in a process of debugging, and narrowed down an issue as below. Essentially, why the first line output is Fibonacci sequence but the second output are all 0s? What exactly prev and next do here?

For your convenient, here is the minimalist codes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>


using namespace std;
int main(){
  vector<int> a(10,1);
  adjacent_difference(a.begin(), std::prev(a.end()), std::next(a.begin()), std::plus<> {});
  copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int> {std::cout, " "});
  cout << endl;
  vector<int> b{0,2,5,4,2};
  adjacent_difference(b.begin(), std::prev(b.end()), std::next(b.begin()) , std::plus<> {});
  copy(b.begin(), b.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int> {std::cout, " "});
  return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 
0 0 0 0 0 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing `std::adjacent_difference` does is take the first value of the input set and store it into the first value of the output set.  This means that in the second case the `0` at `b[0]` is written to `b[1]`.  Then the next pass it takes the next element from the input set, `b[1]` in this case, and adds it to the first element, so you get `0 + 0` and store that into the `b[2]`.  Then you take `b[2]` plus `b[1]`, which is again `0 + 0` and store that into `b[3]`.  This goes on for the whole set and you are left with nothing but `0`'s in the vector.